# VS Extension to Record compile time

Tags: visual-studio, vs-extensibility

I want to develop a Visual Studio extension to run each time the developer compile the currently opened solution. The extension should be able to access or calculate the total compile time and persist this time.

Any directions where I should start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps you, but there are a couple of great extensions that do this already:

- [BuildVision](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23d3c821-ca2d-4e1a-a005-4f70f12f77ba)
- [Build Monitor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0c87e47-f4ee-4935-9a59-f2c81ce692ab)

Been using BuildVision for a long time and really like it.

Build Monitor is open source and you can check out the code on GitHub to see how the build timing has been implemented there: https://github.com/vinntreus/BuildMonitor

Comment: Thanks @Mun, I think Build Monitor is enough for me.